# Div height increasing dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

I am using this code for making a fixed position `<div>`

```
var div = $('.PropertyContainer');
var start = $(div).offset().top;

$.event.add(window, "scroll", function() {
    var p = $(window).scrollTop();
    $(div).css('position', ((p) > start) ? 'fixed' : 'static');
    $(div).css('top', ((p) > start) ? '0px' : '');
});​
```

But it's increasing the `<div>` height on scroll and I don't know why.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BJ4U3/)

Comment: can we see a jsfiddle with a css?

Comment: @ItaiSagi here i have added a js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BJ4U3/

Comment: It's because `min-height:70%;` suddenly becomes active but I'm not sure why.

Comment: but i want min-height there i can't change this css

Comment: you want the min height to be 70% and when fixed position is applied the height can't be less than 70% (there it strictly applies min-height).. thats the reason as you scroll height  changes

Answer (score 1):

Somewhy `min-height` is not applicable for div with `position: static;`. Maybe this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJ4U3/5/) will work.

Actualy, you can exclude javascript at all. Just set `position: fixed;` to the `.PropertyContainer` ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BJ4U3/7/))

Comment: `min-height` works fine with `position:static` (default `position` value for elements). Not sure what problem you’re seeing?

Comment: True. Somehow when i removed `position: static;` property - everything worked fine. So I  thought - this is a reason, neglecting other conditions.

Comment: According with explanation of Robin and the goliney's example, will work and resolve the question of rahul.

Answer (score 0):

Because the event you had added is scroll. Put 'load' instead 'scroll' and test.

I edited your live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BJ4U3/1/

Comment: in that case the div goes up with scroll but i want it to stay there only

Comment: @AnishGupta position:fixed will fix the height all the time and i don't want that heigth can be dynamic